# Context-Registered Receiver not being triggered by Custom Action

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a problem: the Broadcast Receiver in one of my apps isn't having its onReceive callback triggered by a custom action broadcast sent by my service from a separate app.

The broadcast receiver is [context-registered](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers), meaning I don't want to declare it in a manifest file anywhere because I don't want broadcasts launching my app. The broadcast is being sent from a service completely separate from the app, so we're dealing with inter-process communication here and a local broadcast won't do.

My suspicion is that i'm not correctly matching the intent action string declared in my broadcast sender (the Service) with my broadcast receiver (the App).

Looking at my code below, what am I doing incorrectly?

**ScannerService.kt**

```
Intent().also { intent ->
    intent.action = "com.foo.bar.example.package.ScannerService.SCANNER_EVENT"
    intent.putExtra("barcode", barcode)
    intent.setPackage("com.nu.rms")
    sendBroadcast(intent)
    Timber.d("Sent broadcast")
}
```

**AppActivity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    registerBroadcastReceivers()
}

private fun registerBroadcastReceivers() {
        val broadcastReceiver = ScannerBroadcastReceiver()
        val filter = IntentFilter().apply { addAction("SCANNER_EVENT") }
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter)
        Timber.d("Registered broadcast receiver")
    }

class ScannerBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Timber.d("Received broadcast")
        StringBuilder().apply {
            append("Action: ${intent.action}\n")
            append("URI: ${intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)}\n")
            toString().also { log -> Timber.d(log) }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a manifest-declared receiver (eg. in case permissions may have to be added there):

```
<receiver
    android:name=".ScannerBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.foo.bar.example.package.ScannerService.SCANNER_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When using a context-registered receiver, the action might be `ScannerService.SCANNER_EVENT` or verbosely `com.foo.bar.example.package.ScannerService.SCANNER_EVENT`.

Comment: Don't manifest declared receivers launch an app whenever an action is broadcasted though? I specifically don't want my apps that aren't running to be launched when the action is broadcasted by my service.

Comment: Your solution was correct though, I had to verbosely use `com.foo.bar.example.package.ScannerService.SCANNER_EVENT` as input to `addAction( )` in my activity's `registerBroadcastReceivers( )` function. Thanks!

Comment: @Cody you've probably already answered your own question with your doubts. while when permissions are involved, a context-registered receiver won't suffice; it is just that `android.permission.INTERNET` is none, which would have to be explicitly requested at run-time (therefore it probably does not matter).

Comment: Yeah. As stated in the docs "*If you declare a broadcast receiver in your manifest, the system launches your app (if the app is not already running) when the broadcast is sent.*" So regardless of permissions being useful or not, manifest-declared receivers simply won't work for my use case since I don't want apps being launched as a result of broadcasts.